# VestaCP Exim is not sending emails

Tags: email, smtp, centos

Recently i did VestaCP install on a new server of my own, and then, created two users and uploaded site&database content to it, and so, everything was working normally, except for one thing, that is the SMTP that for some reason cannot send emails, all the emails that i try to send it become automatically stuck on the exim email queue like frozen emails.

Too, sometimes i receive a bounced message appointing the following error to me: "retry timeout exceeded". By the way, i am receiving emails normally, my inbox is working 100%.

As i recently installed VestaCP on my operating system that is CentOS 6.5, probably it is some configuration that is missing, or such so, because i did not did any config on exim.

I need a solution or some hints to be capable to solve that problem.